# What are examples of when seq_along works, but seq produces unintended results?

Tags: r, seq

What are good examples of when `seq_along` will work, but `seq` will produce unintended results?

From the documentation of `?seq` we have:

> Note that it dispatches on the class of the first argument
>   irrespective of argument names. This can have unintended consequences
>   if it is called with just one argument intending this to be taken as
>   `along.with`: it is much better to use `seq_along` in that case.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This should make the difference clear. Basically, `seq()` acts like `seq_along()` **except** when passed a vector of length 1, in which case it acts like `seq_len()`.  If this ever once bites you, you'll never use `seq()` again!

```
a <- c(8, 9, 10)
b <- c(9, 10)
c <- 10

seq_along(a)
# [1] 1 2 3
seq_along(b)
# [1] 1 2
seq_along(c)
# [1] 1

seq(a)
# [1] 1 2 3
seq(b)
# [1] 1 2
seq(c)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It's probably worth noting that `sample()` exhibits similarly crummy behavior:

```
sample(a)
# [1] 10  8  9
sample(b)
# [1]  9 10
sample(c)
# [1]  8  7  9  3  4  1  6 10  2  5
```

Comment: is there an alternative to `sample()` then or just use `as.numeric(sample(as.character(c)))`?

Comment: @user1317221_G -- I've just used this kind of idea: `safeSample <- function(x) if(length(x) == 1) x else sample(x)`. (Try it out with `safeSample(4:5); safeSample(5)`.)

Comment: *Sigh* That sad moment when a single user has posted all the answers that you are searching for and you need to wait for 2 days to upvote fearing serial upvote script :(

Comment: @BhargavRao Haha. Thanks for the compliment ;)

Comment: When applied to a empty vector, `x <- c()` ,  `seq(x)` and `seq_along(x)` both return `integer(0)`

Comment: @EnriquePérezHerrero Seems like an appropriate return value for a zero-length vector, right?

Answer (score 26):

If the input to seq is length 1 then the outputs between `seq` and `seq_along` will be different

```
x <- 5
for(i in seq(x)){
    print(x[i])
}
#[1] 5
#[1] NA
#[1] NA
#[1] NA
#[1] NA

for(i in seq_along(x)){
    print(x[i])
}
#[1] 5
```

We also see a difference if the input is a vector of Dates

```
x <- Sys.Date() + 1:5
seq(x)
#Error in seq.Date(x) : 'from' must be of length 1
seq_along(x)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: that date example is great!