# How to randomize a vector

Tags: r, vector, random, shuffle

I would like to randomly reorganize the order of the numbers in a vector, in a simple one-line command?

My particular vector V has 150 entries for each value from 1 to 10:

```
V <- rep(1:10, each=150)
```

Comment: The answers here rightly point your toward `sample`.  You might want to check out the warnings [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13732373/1003565) for some dangers that go along with just using sample as is.

Comment: @Dason: the tl;dr is as long as the vector length is guaranteed to be >1, it works.

Comment: @smci The tl;Dr is that it's dangerous because one gets comfortable with it and then when it finally is of length 1 it bites you.

Comment: @Dason I had read that, but noone's yet modified `base::sample` to force use of `seq_along`. Also I don't see where `sample/sample.int` call  `base::seq()` anyway?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Yes.

```
sample(V)
```

From `?sample`:

> For ‘sample’ the default for ‘size’ is the number of items
>        inferred from the first argument, so that ‘sample(x)’ generates a
>        random permutation of the elements of ‘x’ (or ‘1:x’).

Comment: How can I shuffle [1,1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5] such that I get something like this: [5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4]? such that each element could randomly change to another but with keeping the number of each element constant?

Comment: @Rotail: this already does what you want; the `size` argument of `sample` defaults to `size <- length(x)`. (Type `sample` to see the code that does this.)

Comment: yup! Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

Use `sample` function

```
V<-rep(1:10, each=150)

set.seed(001) # just to make it reproducible
sample(V)
```

Comment: `replace=FALSE` is the default value.

Comment: this makes a 150 values from the original 1500