# Randomly mixing elements in vector R

Tags: r, vector, random, mixing

Supposing I have the vector

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Is there any way I could randomly mix its elements?

Or create a vector which would have integer elements from 1 to 6 which do not repeat?

Comment: [First hit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765972/how-to-randomize-a-vector) when googling your title. "This question does not show any research effort".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need `sample` to do that

```
sample(x)
```

If it needs to be repeated, use the `replicated`

```
replicate(3, sample(x))
```