# How to randomise a vector and keep the frequency of the elements fixed?

Tags: r

Extending [this former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765972/how-to-randomize-a-vector), how can I shuffle (randomize) the following vector

```
a1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5)
```

in order to get something like this:

```
a2 = c(5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4)
```

or even better like this:

```
a3 = c(4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 5)?
```

such that each element could randomly change to another but with keeping the number of each element constant?

Comment: Seems a promising idea! I'll also give it a try to see if I can start from there and produce a3. Thanks!

Comment: That's not valid R code. Are you a refugee from Matlab?

Comment: @42-, Matlab does not use commas to separate array elements. I know because I am a Matlab refugee.

Comment: Alas,  some language uses square-brackets and that was the basis of my guess.

Comment: @42- I'm an R citizen exiled to MATLAB by a boss for a while :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this: create a factor from `a1` with randomly shuffled levels and then convert it to integers:

```
as.integer(factor(a1, levels = sample(unique(a1), length(unique(a1)))))
# [1] 5 5 4 4 4 4 3 3 2 1 1 1
```

Comment: This produces a2 not a3, yet.

Comment: Do the same elements have to be adjacent to each other after the second shuffle?

Comment: Or maybe `t <- table(a1); rep(names(t), sample(t))`,`[1] "1" "2" "2" "3" "3" "3" "3" "4" "4" "4" "5" "5"` if you don't care about the run length encoding.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a perfect application for `rle` and its inverse `rep`:

```
rand_inverse_rle <- function(x) { x=sort(x)
   ord=sample (length(rle(x)$values) )  
   unlist( mapply( rep, rle(x)$values[ord], rle(x)$lengths[ord]))}
rand_inverse_rle(a1)
#----------
 [1] 3 3 4 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 1 1
```

This was my reading of a function needed to satisfy the natural language requirements:

```
>  a1 = sample( c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5) )
> a1
 [1] 5 2 5 2 5 1 3 4 2 2 3 1
> rand_inverse_rle(a1)
 [1] 5 5 5 4 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1
> rand_inverse_rle(a1)
 [1] 1 1 3 3 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 4
> rand_inverse_rle(a1)
 [1] 1 1 3 3 4 5 5 5 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: i don't know whether sorting is needed. It _was_ needed for my reading of the English language description, even if the example had already been sorted.. addendum added.

Answer (score 3):

The data:

```
a1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5)
```

First steps:

```
# extract values and their frequencies
val <- unique(a1)

tab <- table(a1)
freq <- tab[as.character(val)]
```

#### Keep original order of frequencies but sample values

```
rep(sample(val), freq)
# [1] 4 4 1 1 1 1 3 3 5 2 2 2
```

#### Keep original frequencies but sample order of values

```
rep(sa <- sample(val), freq[as.character(sa)])
# [1] 4 2 2 2 2 3 3 1 1 5 5 5
```