# Zero trip R for loop

Tags: r, loops

The R code

```
n = 0
for (i in 1:n) {
   cat("\nhello")
}
```

prints `hello` once, which is also the output when n = 1. What is the idiomatic way to write a loop whose body is not executed if n = 0?

Comment: R, for some arcane design reason, decides that 1:0 creates a sequence counting down. You need to use `seq_along` to generate what you want. Also apparently don't use `seq` alone, because that one is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732062/what-are-examples-of-when-seq-along-works-but-seq-produces-unintended-results).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `seq_len`

```
n = 0
for (i in seq_len(n)) {
   cat("\nhello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need `seq_along` (if it is a sequence) or `seq_len` (if it is a single value)

```
n <- 0
for(i in seq_len(n))
     cat("\nhello")
```

The case when `seq_along` should be used when we expect the vector/list etc to have `length` more than 1

```
> n1 <- c(5, 3, 5)
> seq_len(n1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Warning message:
In seq_len(n1) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
> seq_along(n1)
[1] 1 2 3
```

Other case when we have a length of 0

```
> n1 <- integer(0) 
> # n1 <- NULL
> n1
integer(0)
> seq_along(n1)
integer(0)
> seq_len(n1)
Error in seq_len(n1) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning message:
In seq_len(n1) : first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

Thus, there is no perfect solution that works for all cases.  It may depend upon the input